# CURL PHP Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: php, api, curl

I have to make a POST request to a third party API. I'm doing it through CURL, I've been trying for days but I can't get a positive return. Could anyone evaluate if my code is right?
I tested the API in Insomnia and I'm getting feedback, but in php I can only get that feedback.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: '.$authorization, 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$resu = (array) json_decode($output);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Return on variable $ return

> string(4406)
> "{"ClassName":"System.NullReferenceException","Message":"Object
> reference not set to an instance of an
> object.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"
> at Wangkanai.Detection.Collections.InternetExplorer..ctor(String
> agent)\r\n   at Wangkanai.Detection.BrowserResolver.GetBrowser()\r\n
> at lambda_method(Closure , ServiceProvider )\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type
> serviceType)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider
> sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean
> isDefaultParameterRequired)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure ,
> IServiceProvider , Object[] )\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext
> controllerContext)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.d__14.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__22.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext
> context)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next,
> Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__17.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.d__15.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression.ResponseCompressionMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n---
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
> ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> Advise.Start.Gateway.WebAPI.Startup.<>c.<b__8_0>d.MoveNext() in
> D:\Agents\Agent01\_work\47\s\Advise.Start.Gateway.WebAPI\Startup.cs:line
> 84\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception
> was thrown ---\r\n   at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)\r\n   at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":null,"HResult":-2147467261,"Source":"Wangkanai.Detection.Browser","WatsonBuckets":null}"

Solucion:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64)  AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31'");
```

Comment: Make sure you know where to use `$resu` and `$result`.

Comment: `$resu` return is NULL. I was just testing

Comment: What HTTP status code are you seeing in the response?  I have a feeling something maybe wrong in $body but there is no way of knowing for sure.  The status response should tell you where the problem lies.

Comment: The feedback I get is that informed in the question. And `$body` is a json written as a string.

Answer (score -2):

Problem solved, I added the UserAgent

Comment: Please provide your solution, it can help to another SO users.